# Tests that use h2 in-mem db fail on Heroku

Tags: java, spring, heroku, h2

My Spring boot app has some tests that pass fine on my local, but fail on Heroku:

`org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Exception opening port "8082" (port may be in use), cause: "java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)" [90061-196]`

The data source configuration for the `test` profile:

```
@Configuration
public class TestDataSourceConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    @Profile("test")
    public DataSource testDataSource() throws URISyntaxException {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

`application-test.properties`:
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:tesdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
    spring.datasource.username=sa
    spring.datasource.password=

```
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

I know Heroku doesn't support h2, but this shouldn't be the case here as the app itself brings up the db, right?

Maybe I'm wrong, and it is not failing because of Heroku not supporting h2, but I don't have any other process listening on port `8082` (at least that I know of and being initiated from within my app)

Comment: And what values are specified for server.port and management.port?

Comment: would you add your POM/gradle file to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of a discrepency between how tests are run on eclipse and Heroku. Eclipse runs each test separately, which means it runs each test with fresh start run of the whole application. But Heroku runs all the test classes on one machine sequentially. Therefore I have to kill the h2 server after each test class is finished running:

```
@AfterClass
public static void tearDown() throws SQLException {
    webServer.stop();
}
```

Comment: Or alternatively, only start the server once? Surely there's some "one time set up" functionality available in the test framework.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku will pass port number, you would need to use as enviroment variable with name `PORT`.

In order to use this variable to set your application port, you have to add line to your **application-test.properties** :

```
server.port=${PORT:8082}
```

Or **application-test.yml**:

```
server:
     port: ${PORT:8082}
```

In case `PORT` is not set (like in your local environment), then default `8082` would be used.

This should cover `java.net.BindException` exception.

Comment: I still get the same error, although I added `server.port=${PORT:8082}` to application-test.properties. I changed the server port to `6109` and I still get the same error with `8082` port number ! The server port specified in the application is 8443. So, I don't know where `8082` is being defined.

Comment: Are you using h2 console? Maybe try to disable it on test profile?

Answer (score 1):

The db will not be auto generated unless you add this property in your properties file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. The tests pass locally, but on heroku they don't.